# Grouping exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

What kind of "magic" was used to transition from line 2 to the line 3? I really don't understand it :)

[image]

Comment: $5 \cdot 2^n - 6 \cdot 2^{n-1}= 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 2^{n-1} - 6 \cdot 2^{n-1}=(5 \cdot 2  - 6) \cdot 2^{n-1}$. No amgic at all in math.

Comment: In the same way : $5⋅3^n −6⋅3^{n−1} =5⋅3⋅3^{ n−1} −6⋅3^{n−1} =(5⋅3−6)⋅3^{n−1}=9⋅3^{n−1}=3^2⋅3^{n−1}=3^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
&=5(2^n+3^n)-6(2^{n-1}+3^{n-1})\\ 
&=5\cdot 2^n-6\cdot 2^{n-1}+5\cdot 3^n-6\cdot 3^{n-1}\\
&=5\cdot 2\cdot 2^{n-1}-6\cdot 2^{n-1}+5\cdot 3\cdot 3^{n-1}-6\cdot 3^{n-1}\\
&=(5\cdot 2-6)2^{n-1}+(5\cdot 3-6)3^{n-1}\\
&=4\cdot 2^{n-1}+9\cdot 3^{n-1}\\
&=2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}\\
\end{align}$$

Alternatively 
$$\begin{align}
&=5\cdot 2^n-6\cdot 2^{n-1}+5\cdot 3^n-6\cdot 3^{n-1}\\
&=5\cdot 2^n-3\cdot 2^n+5\cdot 3^n-2\cdot 3^n\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

The distributive property, the fact that $2^n=2\cdot2^{n-1}$, and gathering the like terms under the common factors.